# Add jsp global variable to href html

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

**Guys I need to send request to servlet named sendOTP when click the change password button I also want to send the parameter named email along with it.How to do that? Please help!**

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>ADMIN</h1>
<div class="btn-group" >
    <button>VIEW ORDERS</button>
    <button>VIEW PRODUCTS</button>
    <button>VIEW SELLER</button>
    <button>SEND REQUEST</button>
    <a href="http://localhost:8090/Bootathon2_war_exploded/SendOTP?email="+<%=email%>><button>CHANGE PASSWORD</button></a>
    <a href="admin/Login.jsp"><button>LOGOUT</button></a>
</div>
</body>
<%!
    String email;
%>
<%
    email=request.getSession().getAttribute("email").toString();
%>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see a "change password" button.  Anyway, if email is in session scope, then you can access it by using EL.  Please try  ${email} in your JSP.

Comment: Try using  <a href="http://localhost:8090/Bootathon2_war_exploded/SendOTP?email=${email}">  The scriptlet,  declaration and expression are not necessary in this case.